# does unbuffered channel wait for data?

Tags: go, locking, buffer, channel

I have this program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var ch1 = make(chan int)
var ch2 = make(chan int)

func f1() {
    select {
    case <-ch1:
        fmt.Println("ch1")
    }
}
func f2() {
    select {
    case <-ch2:
        fmt.Println("ch2")
    }
}
func main() {
    go f1()
    go f2()
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("no buffered channel will wait?")
    ch1 <- 1
    ch2 <- 2
    fmt.Println("main exits")
}
```

I expect that, as long as f1 and f2 doesn't print anything, it means ch1 and ch2 has nothing inside, so `ch1<-1` and `ch2<-2` should block?

But when run, it prints:

```
no buffered channel will wait?
main exits
```

Why those unbuffered channels `ch1` and `ch2` were not blocked within main?

If I don't call `f1`/`f2` in `main`, it will report a `dead lock` error.

I don't understand what f1/f2 have done to ch1/ch2.

Would you kindly help to explain their behavior?

Comment: the usual conventions is to talk about `buffered` or `unbuffered` channels. Where a `buffered` channel has a `buffer length > 1`, which allows to `push` without waiting for a `pop` operation. On the other hand, as an `unbuffered` channel  has an empty buffer, every `push` operation requires a `pop` from another routine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `f1()` and `f2()` have receive operations. These are *blocking* operations: as long as there is nobody sending anything on the channel, they *wait*.

So you launch `f1()` and `f2()` as new goroutines, and `main()` sleeps. Meanwhile `f1()` and `f2()` are waiting for data from `ch1` and `ch2`.

Then `main()` wakes up, and tries to send a value on `ch1`. This is OK because there is a goroutine ready to receive from it (`f1()`). Then `main()` tries to send on `ch2`, this is also OK, there is `f2()` ready to receive from it.

Then `main()` returns, and app ends (it does not wait for the other goroutines to print).

If you don't launch `f1()` and `f2()` as new goroutines, when `main()` reaches the send statements, there will be nobody ready to receive from the channels, and since it is unbuffered, it will block. And since there won't be any more goroutines running, this is a deadlock.